# Is it possible to stop .NET 2008 Debugger conditionally?

Tags: c#, debugging, dynamic, conditional-statements

How do we stop at some place in code dynamically, say I need to break the code when a condition is true? Say some variable gets certain value?

Comment: You can only do that for native unmanaged code. (Assuming you mean that you want to set a "data changed" type breakpoint.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I don't think thats correct. You can add a conditional breakpoint when debugging Managed C# code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I didn't think it worked for VS2008 though... but I could be thinking of VS2005! (Edit: Yes I was... It was introduced in VS2008 so it's certainly possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a copy of 2008 to verify, but the newer editions (2010 and 2012) you can set a break point and then right click the red circle in the editor to unveil some options to provide a condition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You can add Conditions to breakpoints. Just follow this steps

1. Add your breakpoint
2. Right Click in the breakpoint
3. Click Condition...
4. Add your condition and click OK

You can see more details about it [in this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

To be complete, you can also add (conditional) code to your app:

```
 if (c == d && System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Comment: Nice thought, are there any benifits of this approuch over Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Pro: you can use arbitrarily complex logic, Con: harder to remove, polluting.